# Method setRemoteAccessPointSpec not found

Tags: java, jboss7.x, jca, tuxedo

Getting method `setRemoteAccessPointSpec` not found exception when trying to deploy the `TuxedoAdapter` in Jboss AS7. The error details are as below:

```
14:51:47,250 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ResourceAdapterDeploymentService Thread Pool -- 1) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.ra.deployment."com.oracle.tuxedo.TuxedoAdapter.rar_TuxedoAdapter": org.jboss.msc.service.
StartException in service jboss.ra.deployment."com.oracle.tuxedo.TuxedoAdapter.rar_TuxedoAdapter": JBAS010446: Failed to start RA deployment [com.oracle.tuxedo.TuxedoAdapter]
        at org.jboss.as.connector.services.resourceadapters.deployment.AbstractResourceAdapterDeploymentService$1.run(AbstractResourceAdapterDeploymentService.java:279) [jboss-as-connector-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-red
hat-21]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
Caused by: org.jboss.jca.deployers.common.DeployException: JBAS010472: Deployment com.oracle.tuxedo.adapter.TuxedoResourceAdapter failed
        at org.jboss.as.connector.services.resourceadapters.deployment.AbstractResourceAdapterDeploymentService$AbstractAS7RaDeployer.initAndInject(AbstractResourceAdapterDeploymentService.java:520) [jboss-as-connector-7.5.0.Final
-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.jca.deployers.common.AbstractResourceAdapterDeployer.createObjectsAndInjectValue(AbstractResourceAdapterDeployer.java:1267) [ironjacamar-deployers-common-1.0.31.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.31.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.connector.services.resourceadapters.deployment.ResourceAdapterXmlDeploymentService$AS7RaXmlDeployer.doDeploy(ResourceAdapterXmlDeploymentService.java:185) [jboss-as-connector-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0
.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.as.connector.services.resourceadapters.deployment.ResourceAdapterXmlDeploymentService.start(ResourceAdapterXmlDeploymentService.java:106) [jboss-as-connector-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1980) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1913) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
**Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: JBAS010474: Method setRemoteAccessPointSpec not found**
        at org.jboss.as.connector.util.Injection.inject(Injection.java:130) [jboss-as-connector-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.as.connector.util.Injection.inject(Injection.java:83) [jboss-as-connector-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.as.connector.services.resourceadapters.deployment.AbstractResourceAdapterDeploymentService$AbstractAS7RaDeployer.initAndInject(AbstractResourceAdapterDeploymentService.java:507) [jboss-as-connector-7.5.0.Final
-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
tuxedo-adapter.rar fialed
failed*
```

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this problem. Basically the problem occurred because of common library was being used in my tuxedoAdapter and my web application.

I've created a shared module in Jboss EAP and put all this commonly used jar files in the EAP server's module. The configuration which I did is as per below,

Step 1: I've created one **module.xml** in which I've added the jar which are going to used commonly.

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="common-jars">
<!--<properties>
    <property name="jboss.api" value="private"/>
</properties>-->

<resources>
    <resource-root path="com.bea.core.i18n_1.4.0.0.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="com.bea.core.jatmi_1.3.1.0.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="com.oracle.tuxedo.adapter_1.1.0.0.jar"/>
    <!-- Insert resources here -->
</resources>

<dependencies>
    <module name="javaee.api"/>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
</dependencies>
```

Step 2: Created a directory as following **common\jars\main** in **$EAP-SERVER\modules\system\layers\base**

Step 3: Added **module.xml** and the **jar** files in **$EAP-SERVER\modules\system\layers\base\common\jars\main**

Step 4: Modified **$EAP-SERVER\standalone\configuration\standalone.xml** as per below,

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:1.2">
        <global-modules>
            <module name="common.jars"/>
        </global-modules>
        <spec-descriptor-property-replacement>false</spec-descriptor-property-replacement>
        <jboss-descriptor-property-replacement>true</jboss-descriptor-property-replacement>
        <annotation-property-replacement>false</annotation-property-replacement>
    </subsystem>
```

Step 5: Removed the common jars from **TuxedoAdapter.rar** and my web app war file.

Step 6: Restarted the EAP Server

Great job. It's worked for me. I think this will be helpful someone who might be face this issue.

Cheers.